# Making nameserver for put domain on server ip

Tags: dns, bind, centos7, nameservers

I have a domain and i want to set it to my server(centos 7).
I made a dns server by bind on my server and made 2 nameserver (ns1.myDomain.ir and ns1.myDomain.ir) and set it in my domain configuration, But i cant ping to my domain.
What is the problem?

Comment: If you do not understand DNS and do not want to learn it, choose instead any provider or your registrar to manage your domain name nameservers for you, after which through their interface you need to create an A/AAAA record for the domain name itself and/or `www.` (in this last case you could use a CNAME record too) to point the name to your IP address. Also you are offtopic here since this is not related to programming, have a look instead at [su], [sf] or [Webmaster.SE] depending on the specifics of your problem (your question lacks details and badly obfuscate the name, see RFC2606)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek , How can i learn DNS? where can i learn do that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the domain registrar, you need to specify the authorised DNS server for your domain. My suggestion is to use the domain registrar's DNS server for resolution and create a zone file there for your domain and enter the A records and other records for your use case.

To have a domain working you don't need to setup your on DNS (bind) server.